# Converting a huge txt file

Tags: python, database, file, converters

I have a huuge csv file (524 MB, notepad opens it for 4 minutes) that I need to change formatting of. Now it's like this:

1315922016 5.800000000000 1.000000000000
1315922024 5.830000000000 3.000000000000
1315922029 5.900000000000 1.000000000000
1315922034 6.000000000000 20.000000000000
1315924373 5.950000000000 12.452100000000

The lines are divided by a newline symbol, when I paste it into Excel it divides into lines. I would've done it by using Excel functions but the file is too big to be opened.
First value is the number of seconds since 1-01-1970, second is price, third is volumen.

I need it to be like this:

```
01-01-2009 13:55:59 5.800000000000 1.000000000000 01-01-2009 13:56:00 5.830000000000 3.000000000000
```

etc.

Records need to be divided by a space. Sometimes there are multiple values of price from the same second like this:

1328031552 6.100000000000 2.000000000000
1328031553 6.110000000000 0.342951630000
1328031553 6.110000000000 0.527604200000
1328031553 6.110000000000 0.876088370000
1328031553 6.110000000000 0.971026920000
1328031553 6.100000000000 0.965781090000
1328031589 6.150000000000 0.918752490000
1328031589 6.150000000000 0.940974100000

When this happens, I need the code to take average price from that second and save just one price for each second.
These are bitcoin transactions which didn't happen every second when BTC started. 
When there is no record from some second, there needs to be created a new record with the following second and the values of price and volumen copied from the last known price and volumen.

Then save everything to a new txt file.

I can't seem to do it, I've been trying to write a converter in python for hours, please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some of your code so we can see where we can help?

Comment: Nothing I tried got me even 10% of the job done so I don't have anything.

Comment: Would you please explain how `01-01-2009 13:55:59 1586.12 220000 01-01-2009 13:56:00 1586.12 220000` derives from the input?

Comment: I imagine what needs to be done:
1) Reading a single line from a file
2) Checking if it's the next second after the last record's
If so, adding the price and volumen values to a variable and increasing a counter for later use in calculating the average
3) If the second is not the next second, copy values of last price and volumen.
4b) Divide timestamps like "1328031552" into seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years. Somehow take care of gap years.
5) Arrange values in the 01-01-2009 13:55:59 1586.12 220000 order
6) Add the record to the end of the new database file.

Comment: How do you get values like 1586.12 and 22000 when the inputs are values like 5.8 and 1.0?

Comment: 4a) Subtract number of seconds between 1970-01-01-00:00 and Jan 12, 2009 (the time of first bitcoin transaction ever)

Comment: Bill Bell - sorry, fixed that. Should've been 01-01-2009 13:55:59 5.800000000000 1.000000000000

Comment: Why in heaven do you want two items of data in the same record (date, time, value, volume)?

Comment: Because my friend with whom I am making an automated crypto-currency trading bot already wrote a simulator that reads data formatted like this. We run simulations for different parameters many times.

In order to avoid the program converting a 500 mb text file everytime we run it, we need to convert it once and for all.

Comment: Honestly I think I will be able to handle the calculations, the thing I can't seem to do is getting the python code to read just the first X characters in the file and saving it as a timestamp variable, then next Y characters and saving as price variable and then next Z characters and saving as volumen variable.

I'm also not sure how to save the new string to the end of a text file in python.

Answer (score 1):

`shlex` is a lexical parser. We use it to pick the numbers from the input one at a time. Function `records` groups these into lists where the first element of the list is an integer and the other elements are floating points.

The loop reads the results of `records` and averages on times as necessary. It also prints two outputs to a line.

```
from shlex import shlex
lexer = shlex(instream=open('temp.txt'), posix=False)
lexer.wordchars = r'0123456789.\n'
lexer.whitespace = ' \n'
lexer.whitespace_split = True

import time

def Records():
    record = []
    while True:
        token = lexer.get_token()
        if token:
            token = token.strip()
            if token:
                record.append(token)
                if len(record)==3:
                    record[0] = int(record[0])
                    record[1] = float(record[1])
                    record[2] = float(record[2])
                    yield record
                    record=[]
            else:
                break
        else:
            break

def conv_time(t):
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(t))

records = Records()

pos = 1
current_date, price, volume = next(records)
price_sum = price
volume_sum = volume
count = 1

for raw_date, price, volume in records:
    if raw_date == current_date:
        price_sum += price
        volume_sum += volume
        count += 1
    else:
        print (conv_time(current_date), price_sum/count, volume_sum/count, end=' ' if pos else '\n')
        pos = (pos+1)%2
        current_date = raw_date
        price_sum = price
        volume_sum = volume
        count = 1

print (conv_time(current_date), price_sum/count, volume_sum/count, end=' ' if pos else '\n')
```

Here are the results. You might need to do something about significant digits to the rights of decimal points.

```
2011-09-13 09:53:36 5.8 1.0 2011-09-13 09:53:44 5.83 3.0
2011-09-13 09:53:49 5.9 1.0 2011-09-13 09:53:54 6.0 20.0
2011-09-13 10:32:53 5.95 12.4521 2012-01-31 12:39:12 6.1 2.0
2012-01-31 12:39:13 6.108 0.736690442 2012-01-31 12:39:49 6.15 0.9298632950000001
```

Comment: That's an intermediate result.

Comment: Full result available now.

Comment: I am so grateful, this is amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Code slightly improved, same results.

Answer (score 0):

1) Reading a single line from a file

```
data = {}
with open(<path to file>) as fh:
    while True:
        line = fh.readline()[:-1]
        if not line: break

        values = line.split(' ')
        for n in range(0, len(values), 3):
            dt, price, volumen = values[n:n+3]
```

2) Checking if it's the next second after the last record's
  If so, adding the price and volumen values to a variable and increasing a counter for later use in calculating the average
3) If the second is not the next second, copy values of last price and volumen.

```
            if not dt in data:
                data[dt] = []

            data[dt].append((price, volumen))
```

4) Divide timestamps like "1328031552" into seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years.
  Somehow take care of gap years.

```
for dt in data:
    # seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, years = datetime (dt)
```

... for later use in calculating the average

```
    p_sum, v_sum = 0
    for p, v in data[dt]:
        p_sum += p
        v_sum += v

    n = len(data[dt])
    price = p_sum / n
    volumen = v_sum / n
```

5) Arrange values in the 01-01-2009 13:55:59 1586.12 220000 order
6) Add the record to the end of the new database file.

```
    print(datetime, price, volumen)
```